# Set values of a column in pandas dataframe based on values in other columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I want to set the value of a column(Z) in a pandas dataframe based on the values in other columns (X,Y):

Here is a sample code for that:

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    #print(i, row['Z'])
    if row['X'] == 1 and row['Y'] == 0:
        row['Z'] = 1
    if row['X'] == 0 and row['Y'] == 1:
        row['Z'] = 0
    if row['X'] == 0 and row['Y'] == 0:
        row['Z'] = 2
    if row['X'] == 1 and row['Y'] == 1:
        row['Z'] = 3
```

what is the way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
m1 = df['X'] == 0
m2 = df['X'] == 1
m3 = df['Y'] == 0
m4 = df['Y'] == 1

df['Z'] = np.select([m2 & m3, m1 & m4, m1 & m3, m2 & m4], [1,0,2,3])
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to code the Z value, you could do  about

```py
df['Z'] = df['X'] + 2 * df['Y']
```

if that's not the case, you use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) afterwards :

```py
df['Z'] = df['Z'].map({1:0, 2:1, 0:2, 3:3})
```